# Rolling 7 day average using calculated averages

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Quick setup that can be used in a fiddle.

```
create table tbl
(avgdate date, avgvalue numeric(10,2));

insert into tbl values ('2021-01-01',10.4);
insert into tbl values ('2021-01-02',13.1);
insert into tbl values ('2021-01-03',11.35);
insert into tbl values ('2021-01-04',3.4);
insert into tbl values ('2021-01-05',7.12);
insert into tbl values ('2021-01-06',16.76);
insert into tbl values ('2021-01-07',17.2);
insert into tbl values ('2021-01-08',13.76);
insert into tbl values ('2021-01-09',10.56);
insert into tbl values ('2021-01-10',null);
insert into tbl values ('2021-01-11',null);
insert into tbl values ('2021-01-12',null);
```

I'm looking to write something along the lines of

```
select avgdate,
   case when avgvalue is not null then avgvalue
   else
   --avg of past 7 days
end
from tbl
```

Normally I'd use the lag function or rownumber to pick out the previous rows values and average them which works for the 10th, but my logic hits a bug when it needs to include calculated rows.  Jan 12th should be the average values for 5th through 9th, plus the calculated values for the 10th and 11th.

Comment: You talk about the "calculated value" for `avgvalue` however you don't tell us what that calculation is.What are you expected results here? If you want the average of the last 7 rows, what's wrong with a windowed `AVG`?

Comment: Having you already tried a moving average   avg(avgvalue) OVER(ORDER BY avgdate
     ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) ?

Comment: @Larnu  -   The calculated value is the average. Jan 11th is average of jan 4th to 10th. Jan 10th is the average of Jan 9 to 3rd.  So Jan 11th is really the average of (jan 4th to 9th + avg of jan 3rd to 9th).    Jan 12th would nest this one further,  being avg(Jan 5th to 9th + avg (jan 3rd - 9th) + avg  (jan 4th to 9th + avg of jan 3rd to 9th)...and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much the code you want:

```
coalesce(avgvalue,
         avg(avgvalue) over (order by date rows between 7 preceding and 1 preceding)
        )
```

Wait.  That chooses the previous 7 values some of which might be `NULL`.  You can use `apply` for this purpose:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(t.avgvalue, t2.avgvalue7)
from tbl t outer apply
     (select avg(t2.avgvalue) as avgvalue7
      from (select top (7) t2.avgvalue
            from tbl t2
            where t2.avgvalue is not null and
                  t2.date < t.date
            order by t2.date desc
           ) t2
     ) t2;
```

Comment: close...this brings back 11.45 for Jan 10th as it should, but also brings the same value for Jan 11 and 12th.    Jan 11th should be avg(jan 4th to 9th + 11.45) where 11.45 is the value calculated for Jan 10th.   Jan 12th should be avg (Jan 5-11th) where Jan 10th is the avg of 3rd - 9th) and Jan 11th is the avg of jan 4th to 10th.

Comment: I should be able to calc Jan 30th from values entered from Jan 1 to 7th, each day after Jan 7th being calculated from those 7 rows.  I can do this with cursors and a couple more hacky methods the involve looping.  Looking for a non-loop or cursor answer.

Comment: @Twelfth . . . Are you saying that you want the averages to accumulate?

Comment: I'm still trying to find an answer to this question, haven't found anything that can accumulate the averages in a set based fashion.